# URL in anchor tag not working right

Tags: url, anchor, shared-hosting

I'm hosting 2 domains on a single shared hosting account. 
Let's say I have 2 domains xyz.com and abc.com

The contents of abc.com are placed in `public_html/abc.com` directory.

In my index.php of the domain abc.com I.e.
in `public_html/abc.com/index.php`

I'm using an anchor tag.

`<a title=”Author: pqr on Google+” href=”https://plus.google.com/u/0/01010101010?rel=author” target=”_blank” rel=”author”>Click here</a>`

but when I click "Click here" I am redirected to `www.abc.com/https://plus.google.com/u/0/01010101010?rel=author`

How do I remove `www.abc.com` from `www.abc.com/https://plus.google.com/u/0/01010101010?rel=author`

Comment: You are using `”` in your code examples. You probably mean `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes work well.

```html
 <a title='Author: pqr on Google+' href='https://plus.google.com/u/0/01010101010?rel=author' target='_blank' rel='author'>Click here</a>
```